# LWC JEST: TypeError: expect(...).toBeAccessible is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am facing following error while running lwc test in newly created Salesforce DX project. I have installed JEST using  sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup command.

This error I am facing only for assertion  `await expect(element).toBeAccessible();`
For other assertion `expect(div.textContent).toBe('Hello, World!');` No error.

```
TypeError: expect(...).toBeAccessible is not a function
    at Object.toBeAccessible (C:\Users\JEST\JESTProject\force-app\main\default\lwc\hello\__tests__\hello.test.js:26:31)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\\JEST\JESTProject\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:333:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn ..........................................
```

lwc component and test is copied from lwc recipe repository - https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/hello

```
   it('is accessible', async () => {
        const element = createElement('c-hello', {
            is: Hello
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        await expect(element).toBeAccessible();
    });
```

If I am running this test in project cloned from lwc recipe repository then I am not facing this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jest](https://jestjs.io/) by default does not support testing Accessibility.

You will need to make sure you use the [Salesforce Accessibility Automation Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/10/automated-accessibility-testing-with-sa11y)

We have a blog post detailing how to setup and get [started](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/10/automated-accessibility-testing-with-sa11y) with it.

Key Steps are as follows

1. Make sure to Install `@sa11y/jest` as dev dependency.

   `npm install -D @sa11y/jest`
2. Create a setup file that registers the `toBeAccessible()` sa11y matcher so that it can be used with `expect()`

You will need a file named `jest-sa11y-setup.js` with below code

```
import { registerSa11yMatcher } from '@sa11y/jest';

registerSa11yMatcher();
```

3. Include the newly created setup file into your generic jest config file. So your jest.config.js file should look like below

   ```
    const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

   const setupFilesAfterEnv = jestConfig.setupFilesAfterEnv || [];
   setupFilesAfterEnv.push('<rootDir>/jest-sa11y-setup.js');

   module.exports = {
       ...jestConfig,
       setupFilesAfterEnv
   };
   ```

Once you have all the above your Jest code should work fine.